# Compare data class in Kotlin without ID

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class in Kotlin, which has number of properties, one of which is `ID`. But when I actually use `compare` function in code, I would like to exclude this `ID` property when comparing. Is there any way to do that except manually boilerplating `compare` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`copy()` function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying) on one of your data class instances to create a copy of it "altering *some* of its properties". e.g.:

```
data class User(val id: Long, val name: String)

val a = User(1, "John")
val b = User(2, "John")

println(a == b) // false
println(a.copy(id = b.id) == b) // true
```

Creating a copy of one of your data class instances and altering the id to be the same as the other instance you want to compare against allows to effectively ignore that property.

You could also copy both data class instances and set `id` to some common value but if you are only doing one-off comparisons then this would be an unnecessary call to `copy()`.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for. I can implement such compare method in data class itself in 1 line. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

A data class generates the `equals` function (`compare` is not generated) based on the properties that are declared in the primary constructor, so if you want it not to compare the IDs, you'll have to move the `ID` property out of the primary constructor.

The obvious part is that you have to move the property to the body of the class, but then you'll also have to make it a `var` since it won't be initialized in the primary constructor (you can't have it be a `val` and initialize it to a default value in the `init` block, because then you can't assign to it in the secondary constructor).

An example of how you can do this:

```
data class User(val id: Long, val name: String)

data class ModifiedUser(val name: String) {

    var id: Long = 0

    constructor(id: Long, name: String) : this(name) {
        this.id = id
    }

}

val u1 = User(1, "John")
val u2 = User(2, "John")

println(u1 == u2) // false

val m1 = ModifiedUser(1, "Sally")
val m2 = ModifiedUser(2, "Sally")

println(m1 == m2) // true
```

It's up to you to decide which way suits you better, but maybe it's easiest to just override `equals` ([and by implication, `hashCode`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/7079453)) to get the desired result, at least it contains the code related to this in just once place, while the above solution can complicate your class quite a bit.

Comment: Wow, all this not to write`equals`?

Comment: For those wondering about skipping `val` in `val id: Long`, you can't do that because the data class primary constructor must have only `val` or `var` parameters.